# Components not added to JPanel object

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, jpanel

This is a tutorial example and `pnl.add(field); pnl.add(txtArea);` not compiling.  Why not?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class KeyStrokes extends JFrame implements KeyListener {
    JPanel pnl = new JPanel();

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        KeyStrokes gui = new KeyStrokes();
    }

    JTextField field = new JTextField(38);
    JTextArea txtArea = new JTextArea(5, 38);
    pnl.add(field);
    pnl.add(txtArea);

    public KeyStrokes() {
        super("Swing Window");
        setSize(500, 200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(pnl);
        setVisible(true);
        field.addKeyListener(this);
    }

    public void keyPressed (KeyEvent event){
        txtArea.setText("Key Pressed");
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent event){
        txtArea.append("\nCharacter :" + event.getKeyChar());
    }

    public void keyReleased (KeyEvent event){
        int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
        txtArea.append("\nKey Code :" + event.getKeyText(keyCode));
    }
}
```

Comment: bcz you can't do that outside of some method.

Comment: "This is a tutorial example" Where did you find this code?

Comment: I misunderstood the tutorial instructions.  your are right thanks it worked!

Answer (score 2):

That's because you can not make those statements outside of a method, note that you can declare variables in the global scope you are in. Move it to the `KeyStrokes()` method, just before the `setVisible(true)` statement. And then `KeyStrokes()` would be something like this:

```
public KeyStrokes() {
    super("Swing Window");
    setSize(500, 200);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    add(pnl);
    pnl.add(field);
    pnl.add(txtArea);
    setVisible(true);
    field.addKeyListener(this);
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear it, please, mark this as the correct answer @WStruss.

Comment: How?  I'm new to this too! Ok so would you say that you can create objects in memory but to use "add" statements they have to be in some method?

Comment: You are not creating objects directly on the memory, this is a high level language that runs on a VM, it already allocates a piece of memory for you (the stack), and whenever you create something in runtime it asks for more (the heap). You create instances of a classes (`objects`) in the global scope of your class, but, to apply statements on those objects those statements has to be contained in a method. See this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work